# Vuejs. Компонент динамического списка

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Есть компонент:

Шаблон:

```
<li :class="{active: active}" class="list-item">
    <span v-if="model.child" >+</span><span @click="activeSet">{{ model.name }}</span>
    <ul v-if="model.child && model.child.length">
        <item :model="item" :key="item.id" v-for="(item,index) in model.child"></item>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Код компонента:

```
Vue.component('item',{
props: ['model'],
template : '#item-template',
data: function () {
    return {
        active: false,
    }
},
methods: {
    activeSet: function(){
        var self = this;
        window.Event.$emit('deactive');
        this.active = true;
        axios.get('api.php',{
            params : {
                folder : self.model.path
            }
        }).then(function(response){
            if(response.data.folders && response.data.folders.length)
                self.model.child = response.data.folders;
        });
    }
},
mounted: function(){
    var self = this;
    window.Event.$on('deactive',function(){
        self.active = false;
    });
}
} );
```

App:

```
var app = new Vue({
el: '#app',
data: {
    treeData : []
},
mounted: function(){
    var self = this;
    axios.get('api.php',{
        params : {
            folder : '/'
        }
    }).then(function(response){
        self.treeData = response.data.folders;
    });
},
});
```

Отображение дочерних списков происходит только после клика на соседний элемент. Как заставить его выводить данные в момент их изменения?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Документация](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9)

```
self.$set(self.model, 'child', response.data.folders);
```